# How can i make a video on youtube play once the countdown ends?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make this countdown redirect to a YouTube video once its completed? I would like it to play a music video that gets timed perfectly with the drop for when the time exactly hits midnight (don't worry I have the correct time it needs to be in).

```
<p id="display"></p>

<script>
var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 31, 2019 23:59:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Event Over!";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want to *redirect* to the youtube video then you can just use

```
location.replace(youtubeUrl);
```

at your desired timing.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp) is what `location.replace` does. It just redirects your visitor to the specific URL, and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_loc_replace) is the example of how to use it in action.

Comment: i have tried this by adding it at   if (distance < 0) and it hasnt worked

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please see the example of how to use it and try it again. It should work.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it. That's how it works here.